# Parsing json to generic list in C#

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have Json Like value name pair. I need to convert to Generic list.

{
"options": {
"32": "S",
"4": "SM",
"33": "M",
"34": "L",
"35": "XL",
"37": "XXL",
"38": "XXXL"
}
}

My class like

```
public class Options
{
    public int optionId { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
}
```

How to convert json to `List<Options>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert your json to `Dictionary<string, string>` and then convert it to your model like this:

```
  public class OptionDictionary
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> Options { get; set; }
    }
    public class Options
    {
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public string OptionName { get; set; }
    }
  
  var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OptionDictionary>(json).Options.Select(x=>new Options(){OptionId = int.Parse(x.Key), OptionName = x.Value}).ToList();
```